# Finite comprehension of an infinite list

Tags: haskell

I typed the following into ghci, thinking that one of two things would happen: 1) The interpreter would hang, searching every member of an infinite list for matches to a predicate; or 2) through behind-the-curtains Haskell jujitsu, the interpreter would somehow figure out that the sequence terminates at 4 and stop there.

```
[x | x <- [1..],5>x]
```

Outcome 1 was what happened.  Now, outcome 2 was a lot to ask for.  But since a human can prove that the sequence terminates at 4, might there be a way to get the interpreter to do it?  Could this be rewritten in such a way that it does terminate?  In fact, is there *ever* a predicate which makes a finite comprehension out of an infinite list?

Comment: `takeWhile (< 5) [1..]`

Comment: @Mog: While I agree with you on your comment, isn't it cheating since you've somewhat changed the meaning of the comprehension?

Comment: The capability of a human to prove something about a program is not always something an automatic program can mimic: you may be able to reason that some specific program can terminate, but in general this is not possible to compute (it's the halting problem, which is undecidable). And you can write any code you want in a list comprehension, so I believe in the general case the compiler will have very difficult time reasoning about your list comprehensions.

Comment: I do agree that it's cheating, but whether this way or by using `Data.List.Ordered`, you have to help Haskell a tiny bit here, don't you?

Comment: @mog But what about comprehensions having gaps yet still finite?  Consider this contrived example: let f x = (2048 / ((-2) ^ x)) > 1.  Then `[x | x <- [1..], f x]` gives `[2,4,6,8,10` yet `takeWhile f [1..` gives `[]`

Comment: @gcbenison: `takeWhile` is no magic bullet. It only works if the desired output list is a prefix of the input list.

Comment: @gcbenison: well in more elaborated cases I guess you'll have to decide of a stop condition yourself or do some pruning: here it could be `takeWhile f.filter even $ [1..]`

Comment: However, `takeWhile (< 5) [1,2,3,5,4]` will produce only `[1,2,3]`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> But since a human can prove that the sequence terminates at 4, might there be a way to get the interpreter to do it?

In this simple case, yes. But there cannot exist a general algorithm to determine if an expression is true or false for all natural numbers `>n` for some `n`, because Haskell is Turing-complete, so it's impossible to prove that an expression even represents a terminating program for all natural numbers.

Even if your expression were limited to basic integer arithmetic, its truth would still be undecidable in the general case.

> Could this be rewritten in such a way that it does terminate?

As Mog wrote in the comment, it's `takeWhile (< 5) [1..]`.

Comment: So would you agree with @Kilian that "it would be possible to add symbolic reasoning to the interpreter so that it could prove that no further elements will be acceptable and then terminate"?

Comment: @gcbenison: yes and no. Yes, it might be possible. No, it would not work in the general case, so the interpreter could only *guess* the right answer in some cases. Either the language would have to be radically changed, or you're turning the interpreter into a theorem prover.

Comment: @larsmans "turning the interpreter into a theorem prover" as it ought to be anyways. ;)

Comment: Wow, this is the first reference to the halting problem I've seen on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ok for the solution, but an explanation of why `[x | x <- [1..],5>x]` hangs would have been useful. Only when I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13541110/5825294) did I realize how dumb I was.

Answer (score 8):

`takewhile` is the correct solution for your specific problem, as mentioned above.

However, this is only because in your case, all acceptable arguments come before all unacceptable arguments, and the general list comprehension doesn't obey that constraint. It would certainly possible to add symbolic reasoning to the interpreter so that it could prove that no further elements will be acceptable and then terminate. (In fact, the sophisticated type system in Haskell would be quite useful in implementing such reasoning.) But it would not make sense to add this to the standard `[|]` operator, since the detector would have to run on *all* list comprehensions that are evaluated, and would very often fail to contribute anything except much more computing expense.

Answer (score 2):

> "But since a human can prove that the sequence terminates at 4, might
>   there be a way to get the interpreter to do it?"

Good question. The difficult thing is not the proof that it terminates at 4, but the idea that it could possibly terminate at 4, followed by the insight that this is indeed so.