# Pi summation running infinitely

Tags: haskell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finite comprehension of an infinite list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336392/finite-comprehension-of-an-infinite-list)

I've been playing a bit with Haskell so I tried to give it a shot at computing Pi to a degree, however, the solution seems to run infinitely for no particular reason. I can't seem to figure it out.

Here is what I currently have:

```
numerPi :: Int -> Int
numerPi k = (-1)^(k+1)
denomPi :: Int -> Int
denomPi k = 2*k - 1
termPi :: Int -> Float
termPi k = fromIntegral(numerPi(k)) / fromIntegral(denomPi(k))
quarterPi = sum([termPi(x) | x <- [1..], termPi(x) > 0.00001])
```

Doing `4 * quarterPi` in ghci just seems to go on forever. I apologize if the question is too easy but I can't get it to work and Google isn't helping in the slightest.

**Edit:
This is a duplicate of** [Finite comprehension of an infinite list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336392/finite-comprehension-of-an-infinite-list)

Comment: I've also tried lowering the threshold to 0.1, doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Besides that, you'll also want to check whether `abs $ termPi x` is larger than the threshold. Also, function application in Haskell doesn't need parentheses.

Comment: I was apparently using incorrect keywords for my search. Thanks.