# Haskell laziness in list comprehensions

Tags: haskell, range, list-comprehension

I wanted to take a sum of all even numbers <= 1000.

The following code:

`sum [x | x <- [1..1000], even x]` (I know it can be done with [2,4..1000], this is for practice)

reports that the sum is `250500`.

However:

`sum [x | x <- [1..], even x && x <= 1000]`

never finished and has to be interrupted!

I thought that I could safely write `[1..]`, which is an infinite list, because Haskell would not try to evaluate it.

Furthermore, I thought that it would simply start going x by x, checking them and adding them.

So why does the above fail to produce a result?

Comment: I'm not positive, but I think the problem is that Haskell needs to check every element of the (infinite) list `[1..]` to make sure it gets all the elements that satisfy the given predicate. It can't make the "intuitive" leap to realize that only the first 1000 elements can satisfy it.

Comment: Haskell isn't a theorem prover. It doesn't know that there can't be an element `<1000` after 1000.

Comment: Yes it seems so obvious now... I could've just put `|| x == 100000000` after that... I don't know how I overlooked that....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finite comprehension of an infinite list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336392/finite-comprehension-of-an-infinite-list)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
sum [x | x <- [1..], even x && x <= 1000]
```

translates to something like

```
sum (filter (\x -> even x && x <= 1000) [1..])
```

The range expression (or, desugared, `enumFrom`) continues to generate values and `filter` keeps discarding them (it doesn't know there'll never be another element that satisfies the predicate), but `sum` never gets to the end of the list, so it can't return a result. You want to stop evaluating the list as soon as you see the first value greater than 1000:

```
sum (takeWhile (<= 1000) $ filter even [1..])
```

Comment: As I commented on the question, it seems obvious now and I don't know how I overlooked it. Could you explain what that backslash before the first x in the second snippet means please?

Comment: @yannbane: That is a lambda expression. It makes an anonymous function that takes the argument `x`.